# Batch rename places a space before variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am renaming a bunch of files that begin with `TB-Practice` to begin with `P-`.

So far I have this batch

```
pushd %~dp0
for %%i in ("TB-Practice*.pdf") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
::Cuts off 1st eleven chars, then appends prefix
::P- is put in front of the file name
ren "%fname%" "P-%fname:~11%"
goto :eof
```

Unfortunately instead of ending up with `P-Filename` I end up with `P- Filename` which is incompatible with the current format I'm using for these files.

What am I doing wrong? There isn't a space anywhere when declaring the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original file names all contain a space trailing `TB-Practice`, it is much easier to split on them.

On cmd line:

```
@for %A in ("TB-Practice *.pdf") do @for /f "tokens=1*" %B in ("%A") do @echo Ren "%A" "P-%C"
```

or in a batch file:

```
pushd %~dp0
for %%A in ("TB-Practice *.pdf") do for /f "tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do Ren "%%A" "P-%%C" 
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me realized *after* I posted that the batch doesn't remove that space after `TB-Practice` and that's why a space was left over. Solved.